# Select 2 v4.0.5 not working in bootstrap modal 4

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I checked most of the issues related to select2 with respect to bootstrap modal, however, none seems working.

My Modal looks like

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select id="mySelect2">
                        
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, here comes the some way trying to initialize select2

## 1

```
<script>
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal'),
        tags: true
    });
</script>
```

## 2

```
<script>
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal .modal-body'),
        tags: true
    });
</script>
```

## 3

adding additional line on both 1 and 2

```
<script>
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal .modal-body'),
        tags: true
    });
</script>
```

## 4

Removed `tabindex="-1"` and tried all steps from 1-3

All, I am trying is to initialize `select2` with dynamic option creation.

None, of this method works. Could someone point me, what I am missing :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, by looking at your attempts, it looks like it should have worked. However, sometimes what happens is that your modal is yet to be loaded, however, the select2 is already initialized. In those cases, it would be better to initialize this select on `shown.bs.modal`. I feel that it should be a problem with your case as well. Otherwise, your attempts should have worked.

The following code should do the job if that's the case:

```
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(this).find('#mySelect').select2({
                dropdownParent: $(this).find('.modal-body'),
                tags: true
            });
        });
```